# Mongo sort on array field

Tags: arrays, mongodb, sorting

I have a mongo collection with docs

```
   {a:1,b:[2,3,4]}
   {a:2,b:[1,5,6]}
   {a:3,b:[3,4,5]}
```

I want to sort by field b so that the result is

```
   {a:2,b:[1,5,6]}
   {a:3,b:[3,4,5]}
   {a:1,b:[2,3,4]}
```

Where arrays are sorted by highest elements in them.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

When you sort by an array field, the docs are ascending sorted using the minimum value of each doc's elements and for descending, it's the max value.

So for your case it's just:

```js
db.coll.find().sort({b: -1})
```

Comment: but what if there's tie say b:[1,5,6] and b:[3,4,6] in this case the order needs to be 1st [1,5,6] since 5 is next higher element and then [3,4,6]

Comment: @NeilKumar That's a different question, and couldn't be handled this way.